# finding the lowest value integer from data stored in an array using php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array called $quotes and when I print_r an example of the results are like this:

```
Array ( [id] => advshipper [methods] => Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [id] => 2-0-0 [title] => Small Parcels [cost] => 4.5 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 0 ) 
[1] => Array ( [id] => 3-0-0 [title] => Large Parcels up to 1150mm long [cost] => 8.95 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 1 ) 
[2] => Array ( [id] => 4-0-0 [title] => Extra Large Parcels over 1150mm long [cost] => 15 [icon] => [shipping_ts] => [quote_i] => 2 ) ) [module] => Shipping )
```

What I need is a simple way to look at $quotes, find which [cost] has the lowest value and then record, in this example, the [0] so that they can be used in another code segment.

Short of exploding the array and then looping through all the content, is there a simple method to achieve what I want?

Comment: Use `array_filter` with callback to handle your logic.

Comment: What is your php version?

Comment: So, you are lucky. check out my answer

Comment: @StevePrice, Could you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As you are using the version higher than 5.5, you can simply use [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) function:

```
echo min(array_column($quotes['id'],'cost'));
```

And if you want, you can retrieve the id of the row as well:

```
echo min(array_column($quotes['id'], 'cost', 'id'));
```

Comment: This returns a result of 1 in the given example. I'm assuming that relates to it being the first of the data sets in the array. It can't mean $quotes[1] because that is the second most expensive.
Can I just manipulate the result of 1 to give me the correct $quotes[0] result I need?

Comment: @StevePrice, Yes. I updated the code. Actually, you can read the documentation of the function to use it in your own way. It's too easy and clear

Answer (score 0):

```
array_reduce($quotes, function($minimum, $current) {
    return $current['cost'] < $minimum['cost'] ? $current : $minimum;
}, $quotes[0]);
```

This will return the row of `$quotes` that has the lowest value of `cost`.

Comment: Can you explain your answer a little for me please? What would happen if $quotes[2] happened to be the cheapest option?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood that correctly, you need to find the lowest value for cost array.
You can do an array_map to get the values

```
$lowestcost = array_map(function($costval) {
return $costval['cost'];
}, $array);
```

Then you need to use

```
min($lowestcost)
```

Hope this helps